# wpf textbox text binding

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox, inotifypropertychanged

i am trying to bind the text of a textbox to a property in my class, and it is not working, I am editing the property in the code behind but I don't see the string in the textbox
this is the class, and the property i am trying to bind is called songFolder.

```
public class song :  INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string title {get; set; }
    public string artist { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public static string folder;
    public string songsFolder { get { return folder; } set { folder = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("songsFolder"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public song()
    {

    }

    public song(string title, string artist, string path)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.path = path;
    }

}
```

and the xaml, containing the resource and the textbox wich i am tring to bind

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="Song Filler" Height="455" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:song x:Key="song"/>
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="browseBox" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=song}, Path=songsFolder, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Width="auto" Click="Browse">browse</Button>
    </Grid>
```

--------------update----------------
I added the next line to ctor of the window:

```
BrowseBox.DataContext=new song()
```

And while debugging I saw that the property is changing but the text in the textbox isn't.

Comment: Your notify event has the wrong property in it:  `NotifyPropertyChanged("sPath");` Should be `NotifyPropertyChanged("songsFolder")`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it, but it still not working

Comment: It might help us if you explain what's wrong beyond just "not working" ...

Comment: I didn't change the xaml

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors (look in the output window)? if so, please post the details. It might also help if you show us the code-behind of the mainWindow class (or your viewModel if you're using MVVM).

Answer (score 2):

The string passed into the NotifyPropertyChanged event should be the same name of the property itself.

```
public string songsFolder 
{ 
    get 
    { 
      return folder; 
    } 
    set 
    { 
      folder = value; 
      NotifyPropertyChanged("songsFolder"); 
    }
}
```

Also,

try adding UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" to the binding of the textBox

```
<TextBox Name="browseBox" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=song}, Path=songsFolder, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
```

Edit: Maybe the DataContext is not getting set correctly. You can also try this method (W/out a static Key)

Code behind, inside the Ctor of the window:

```
browseBox.DataContext = new song();
```

Then, update textBox finding to:

```
<TextBox Name="browseBox" Text="{Binding Path=songsFolder, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
```

Comment: Added it, still not working. In the code behind I open a folder browser dialog and changing the songsFolder property according to the selected path, but I don't see it in the textbox

Comment: @user1622986 updated.. Set the dataContext of the window (see Edit)

Comment: Can't do that, I am using the window dataContext to bind a list of songs to a listbox.

Comment: @user1622986 change public static string folder; to private string folder;